# Using multiple tiff files as a data store in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, merge, vrt, gdal-merge

I have hundreds of tifs I want to use as a data store on my Geoserver.  So many that QGIS won't merge them for me.  I heard some about .vrt but I never found a clear source of information on the matter.  What would be the best route to get all of my tif files to behave as a single layer in Geoserver?

Comment: I think it might have been answered already here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52367/handling-many-raster-files-in-qgis

Comment: http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adding_data/mosaic.html

Comment: The first answer just shows how to make a .vrt file which Geoserver won't accept, they are useful for working in QGIS or GDAL but not Geoserver.  The second link shows how to load an ImageMosaic into Geoserver assuming you have an ImageMosaic file which as I said in the question I have tiff files.  I'm thinking the answer would be to create an shapefile index of the directory containing the tiffs, how do I create said .shp file? I guess that would answer my question.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you'd want to use the image mosaic plugin:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/index.html

The configuration of the mosaic can be scary, but if all you want is to merge all the images together visually, then put them in a directory and just point the GeoServer image mosaic at it with no other setups, it should self-configure.

Then you might find it's slow.... [the files can be optimized](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/raster_data/processing.html) one by one using command line tools, and you might decide to start showing the data only past a certain scale with a [SLD scale dependency](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rules.html#scale-selection).