# Fetching Tiles for Zoom Level from Data Base

Tags: geoserver, tiles, image-mosaic

I have 6.7 million tiles of 200 x 200 meter each stored in a remote database, Can i plot them on the web dynamically as my zoom level changes or i move towards a new area my DB is queried and files matching this zoom level are fetched, Using GeoServer.

Comment: Yes of course, geoserver does that easily. Where exactly are you stuck? ;)

Comment: please guide me toward the respective documentation or tutorials, also. The database i am talking about is folders and files on a remote server

Comment: Well, what kind of format are those tiles in? Are they georeferenced? If so, how? Metadata?

Comment: files are in tiff format and are GeoRefrefrenced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are plain files, you use the Image Mosaic Plugin: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/268648/51035

If they are in a PostGIS raster database, you can use the Image Mosaic JDBC Plugin: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaicjdbc.html