# Merging rasters in QGIS error

Tags: qgis, raster

I have about 250 rasters (aerial imagery) to merge together in QGIS 3.2. Approx 4.5 gigs in size.

What's the easiest way to merge them? I have tried to "merge" tool a lot but getting various errors such as:

```
ERROR 1: D:/Desktop/1/1233.tif, band 3: An error occurred while writing a dirty block

ERROR 1: D:/Desktop/1/1233.tif, band 1: An error occurred while writing a dirty block

ERROR 1: JPEGPreEncode:Strip/tile too large for JPEG

ERROR 1: WriteEncodedTile/Strip() failed.
```

The rasters are in a .tif format.

Comment: Have you tried the "Mosaic" Function in QGIS? You fine it under "Processing Toolbox". SAGA -> Raster Tools -> Mosaic raster layers. This may handle larger datasets than the Merge function under Raster Tools. Also, do you have enough hard-drive space where you are trying to save the new raster? This answer here: http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-solve-gdal-error-an-error-occurred-while-writing-a-dirty-block/ describes a similar error, because of running out of hd space. The process might be uncompressing the images if they have already been compressed.

Comment: Thinking on it, I am more ESRI based, but we create Raster Catalogs for large raster datasets instead of a Mosaic. Doing a quick Google Search and look on the GIS Se I found this: An option instead of trying to mosaic or merge all the rasters into a single file, would be to create a Raster Catalog. 

The answer provided here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52367/handling-many-raster-files-in-qgis describes the method. The answers here should help. PS Dont forget to upvote the answers that help you.